# Regex to extract some parameters values between nested text

Tags: regex, vba, pcre, word-boundary

I have the below input text for which I want to extract the following values with a regex (I firstly look for a Regex that works for VBA Excel, but I think there is no too much difference if the Regex is for PCRE):

1- the number after `num` --> `3025285000`

2- The ip addresses --> `111.111.112.223` and `13.100.1.11`

3- The Uplink and Downlink values --> `139161` and `6269538`

4- The date and time after `xTime` --> `2019-07-22 18:09:55 -03:00`

input text is like this:

```
{ num:{3025285000} }
{ ipadd:{iPadd:{iPv4add:{111.111.112.223} } } }
{ ipval:{iPadd:{13.100.1.11} } }
{ :{abc:{-} ddf:{-} mainVALUplink:{139161} mainVALDownlink:{6269538} kppacRR:{bbckdo} xTime:{2019-07-22 18:09:55 -03:00 } ppwo:{-} wwe:{-} iiurur:{qCI:{8} wie:{-} iiwww:{-} oop:{-} } } }
```

I've being trying with the following Regex (You can check here https://regex101.com/r/J9kGMy/1)

```
\B\d+\b|\B{\d+\..+\b}|dataVolumeGPRS(Up|Down)link:\B\d+|xTime:{\B\d+
```

But the matches are incomplete or taking more characters, since the current matches are:

Match 1:    Full match  8-17        025285000         Should be `3025285000`

Match 2:    Full match  45-62       {111.111.112.223} Should be `111.111.112.223`

Match 3:    Full match  84-97       {13.100.1.11}     Should be `13.100.1.11`

Match 4:    Full match  138-143     39161             Should be `139161`

Match 5:    Full match  163-169     269538            Should be `6269538`

Match 6:    Full match  196-199     019               Should be `2019-07-22 18:09:55 -03:00`

Match 7:    Full match  201-202     7
Match 8:    Full match  204-205     2
Match 9:    Full match  207-208     8
Match 10:   Full match  210-211     9
Match 11:   Full match  213-214     5
Match 12:   Full match  217-218     3
Match 13:   Full match  220-221     0
Match 14:   Full match  305-307     04

Comment: If you want to use an alternation to get those fields, you could make the match more specific by matching the text in front and capturing the value in a capturing group `num:{(\d+)}|iPadd:{([^{}]+)}|iPv4add:{([^{}]+)}|xTime:{([^{}]+)}`https://regex101.com/r/EmeggH/1 Is the order of the input always the same or can the position of the fields vary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the pattern that you tried, you are using an [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) using the `|`

If you want to match your values in that way you could make the match more specific by matching `num`, `ipAdd` , `iPv4add` or `xTime` and then use a capturing group to capturing what is between `{` and `}`.

Inside the capturing group `(\d+)` you could match 1+ digits using or make use of a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) `([^{}]+)` and match all characters except `{` and `}`

The result will have 4 capturing groups.

```
num:{(\d+)}|iPadd:{([^{}]+)}|iPv4add:{([^{}]+)}|xTime:{([^{}]+)}
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/YImYKM/1)

Comment: Hello, thanks for your help and solution. It seems to work for pcre. The only thing is not capturing uplink nor downlink values. I think could be similar to how you did to capture `num` right?

Comment: @GerCas That is correct, it would look like `num:{(\d+)}|iPadd:{([^{}]+)}|iPv4add:{([^{}]+)}|xTime:{([^{}]+)}|mainVALUplink:{(\d+)}|mainVALDownlink:{(\d+)}`  https://regex101.com/r/YImYKM/2 Is the format of the data always in this order with all the values present and the newlines at consistent places? If that is the case, then you could go for a more efficient match.

Comment: Thanks for your addition. Actually, the different strings are in different columns in same line and there are several lines with the same format. I was thinking in use a single regex to remove unneeded data because of that I was trying with `|` or sign or alternation like you said.

Answer (score 1):

Since each expected result is on a line of its own, the logical solution would be to split the input line-by-line, and then apply simpler individual regexes to them to capture what is needed.

However, the following regex, though lengthy, works as expected:

`num:\s*{\s*(\d+)\s*}[\s\S]+?(?:ip\S+:{\s*([\d\.]+)\s*}[\s\S]+?)[\s\S]+?(?:ip\S+:{\s*([\d\.]+)\s*}[\s\S]+?)[\s\S]+?Uplink:\s*{\s*(\d+)\s*}[\s\S]+?Downlink:\s*{\s*(\d+)}\s*[\s\S]+xTime:{\s*([\s\d-:]*?)\s*}`

Each capture group contains the required data.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/J9kGMy/4)

Comment: Hi CinCout. Thanks for your solution. I see that your regex doesn't use alternation `|`. I thought that only with alternation was possible to get different matches. How would be your solution in order to match uplink and downlink values too?

Comment: @GerCas updated the answer to include Uplink and Downlink

Comment: Thanks so much. It works pretty fine. I only selected the other as answer due to that is smaller.